# ActiveAdmin - using the current_admin_user to filter available actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I have an active admin resource like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Snippet do

  menu label: "Text Snippets"

  config.clear_sidebar_sections!

  index download_links: false do
    column :key if current_admin_user.developer?
    column :description
    column :contents
    default_actions
  end

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :description
      f.input :contents
    end
    f.buttons
  end

end
```

Notice in the `index` block, I'm only adding the `key` column if the current admin user is a developer. I want to apply this kind of filtering to the available actions.

I tried added this at the top of the resource definition:

```
actions current_admin_user.developer ? :all : :index, :edit
```

But I get a `NameError` on `current_admin_user`. For some reason, outside of the configuration blocks, the active admin `current_admin_user` helper doesn't exist.

So, how could I go about filtering actions based on the current user's priviliges?

Comment: have you done  `config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user` in config file?

Comment: @ismaelga no, but that is the default, and it works inside the `index` block.

Comment: oh, I should read all the question first. Sorry. I can't help then. But it's a nice question :) hope you can get an answer

Comment: @AlexCoplan 5 years later but I saw you didn't accept the answer, can you do it now please? Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

you have to use a proc. `current_admin_user` exists only when the app is running, not when you declare your class.

For example

```rb
action_item :only => [:edit], :if => proc { current_admin_user.developer? } do
  # enter code here
end
```

You can also use CanCan for this, and place `controller.authorize_resource` at the beginning. Check the activeadmin documentation for this.

Another way to do it is overriding the action_methods in the ActiveAdmin controller. like this

```
actions :all

controller do
  def action_methods
    if current_admin_user.developer?
      super
    else
      super - ['show', 'destroy', 'new', 'create']
    end
  end
end
```

this works specially good if you have multiple roles to define behavior for.

Lastly, you should use `developer?` instead of `developer` (off course if the `developer` method returns a boolean as I suspect), to be more Ruby idiomatic.

**UPDATE**

in version 0.6+ you should stick with CanCan, for more information check the activeadmin documentation http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/13-authorization-adapter.html#using_the_cancan_adapter

Comment: The one liner didn't work and tried a thousand of variations, but the "controller do" block worked great!